# Object messes up in animation

Tags: animation, armature

[image]I`m new in blender, anyone can tell me what I have done wrong, my object messes up while animating, take a look at the eyes from the image.. and edges became very strange, armatures of the arms are out of places.

Comment: this happens when you dont add keyframes to all your objects and they move to whatever you animated them to do , from the 1st frame , probably this is the same problem , have a look at the separate poses of the objects

Comment: I have added keyframes but still the same. Thanks a lot for your time.